# Have I missed the :mv command in Vim?

Tags: vim

From time to time I want to rename a file while editing it. For example from `.html` to `.xhtml` or so.

To do that in Vim, I must do

```
:saveas new_file
:!rm old_file
```

Is there a built-in command, that allows me to get rid of the `:!rm` part? It's annoying to re-type the old path and filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always define your own. E.g., put this in your .vimrc:

```
" First define a function
function! MoveFunction(newname)
    " get the current file name
    let a:oldname = expand("%:p")
    " save under the new name
    exec "saveas " . a:newname 
    " delete the old file
    call delete(a:oldname) 
endfunction
" Next define a command
command! -nargs=1 MoveTo call MoveFunction(<f-args>)
```

then:

`:MoveTo <new-name>`

should do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I feared, that I'd have to. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no command that will rename both the file on-disk and the buffer at the same time. There are some ways to reduce the amount of typing you have to do, though. For example, Vim will expand % to the name of the current buffer/file, so you could use

```
:!mv % new_file
```

If new_file has the same root name as old_file, you could do this to change just the extension:

```
:!mv % %:r.xhtml
```

where `%:r` expands to the name of the current buffer/file without the extension. See

```
:help filename-modifiers
```

Once you have the file name changed on-disk, you can change your buffer to that name with

```
:e new_file
```

or

```
:f new_file
```

Both commands have file name completion, so you can type just the first few letters of the file name, then <tab> to have Vim complete the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
:!mv old_file new_file
```

You have to save current buffer first, btw!

Answer (score 1):

There's also the Rename.vim plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1928

Answer (score 0):

(now?) There is also the `rename()` function, but then you'll have to track any buffer pointing to the old-filename to apply a `:filename`.

Comment: rename() function has been available since Vim 5.5 (see `:h version5`)